# Can we Implement Oauth2 authorization server with spring boot which supports Client_Crentials & password grant types?

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, authorization

we have an android app and some set of restful services used by that android app.

Want to implement oauth2.0 for those services using spring-boot with grant type password and we want to expose same services to outside world by providing client-credential grant type with oauth2.0

is it possible to do with same authorization server implementation supports both grant types?

Answer (score 0):

Full Disclosure: I work for Ping Identity and we offer an Identity Access Management Solution.

Absolutely!
Check out this resource where you'd set the "authorizationGrantType" to "client_credentials":

> authorizationGrantType: The OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework
>   defines four Authorization Grant types. The supported values are
>   authorization_code, implicit, and client_credentials.
>   :

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2client

If you want to see an example implementation, check out:
https://github.com/pingidentity/pingone-customers-sample-resource-owner.git

This was made to connect to our PingOne for Customers product, but you can get an idea for how the client credentials flow would work since we allow a Post with Client Secret to authenticate.

Comment: That I know.my question is can we implement multiple grant types in same outh2 Authorization server??

Comment: Ah, yes! That shouldn't be a problem. You'll need to have it perform the respective grant flow based on the "grant_type" parameter.